# PHP: is current function running inside an object?

Tags: php, object, scope

Is there any way in PHP to tell if a function is being run from inside or outside a particular class of object?

```
function getToDaChoppa() {
    if( "we're inside the Choppa object" ) {
        $foo = "We're inside";
    } else {
        $foo = "We're outside";
    }
    echo $foo;
}

class Choppa() {
    public function getStatus() {
        getToDaChoppa();
    }
}
```

Running:

```
getToDaChoppa();
( new Choppa )->getStatus();
```

should echo:

We're Outside

We're Inside

Comment: `__CLASS__` will be set in the latter case.

Comment: What does `get_class($this)` return?

Comment: Wait, I lied. `__CLASS__` is only set for functions that are defined **inside** the class. Are you calling a global from inside the class?

Comment: You are asking for us to fix the wrong "solution". You should be asking questions about the problem, that you have, instead of asking about your "solution". Whatever you are doing, checking for whether something is called from class is **the wrong thing to do**.

Comment: @B001 My particular use case is a Template class. I have a particular debugging function that I want to run a little differently if it's being called inside a template (object) or from raw code.

Comment: I think its a perfectly valid question. One that is equally interesting to hear the solution for, because I've never in my years of coding have done something like that :)

Comment: Calling a global function from within a class doesn't carry through any information about the class that called it - you'd need to use `debug_backtrace` or similar to find out where the function was called. Alternatively, pass the instance to the function as a `$context` variable.

Comment: You could always pass through an instance of the class and evaluate that, consider this example: `https://ideone.com/y3r21Q`.

Comment: @MCMXCII this would work if the function is called from an instance of `random` but throws an exception if called from anywhere else

Comment: @WilliamPerron Could always give the parameter the instance is being passed to a default of a blank string, that way anything that calls it outside of a class and doesn't pass an instance of itself will just evaluate to a blank string: `https://ideone.com/y3r21Q`.

Comment: I'm thinking passing a $context parameter might be the way to go -- `if( $context instanceof \MyClass ) {...}`  debug_backtrace in a pinch, but not ideal.

Comment: @MCMXCII from the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php): "If get_class() is called with anything other than an object, an E_WARNING level error is raised."

Comment: @WilliamPerron I've updated the code to reflect this, with a ternary on the default value to only run the `get_class()` if a value is passed.

Comment: @StephenR I don't think modifying the behavior of a global function is the way to go here. There's probably a better to do this using Inheritence or Composition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `debug_backtrace()`, go back one hop, and check if that was made from inside a class. I'm not sure I'd do this in production though...

```
function getToDaChoppa() {
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    if (isset($bt[1]) && array_key_exists('class', $bt[1])) {
        echo "called from class\n";
    } else {
        echo "called directly\n";
    }
}
```

Clarification: if you want it to trigger only for one specific class:

```
function getToDaChoppa() {
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    if (
        isset($bt[1]) &&
        array_key_exists('class', $bt[1]) &&
        $bt[1]['class'] === 'Choppa'
    ) {
        echo "called from class Choppa\n";
    } else {
        echo "called otherwise\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also return `"called from class"` if it is called from a different class than `Choppa` ?

Comment: It will trigger for any class. If you want it to trigger for only one specific class, just check the value of `$bt[1]['class']`.

Answer (score 1):

A function on it's own doesn't know, if it's called from an class or not and that for good reasons. If  the function behaves different, that would lead to very unmaintainable code and hard debugging, etc.

If you need  the calling function and maybe ask, if this function belongs to an class/get the instance, the only way to do this is [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). But in general you really only should do this, for debug code (as the name tells you).

Normally you would just have two functions for each case, or pass an parameter, which stores the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

You could always pass an instance of the class through on top of a default value, then evaluate on the return of a `get_class()`.

```
function getToDaChoppa($that = false) {
    $class = $that ? get_class($that) : '';
    if($class == "Choppa") {
        $foo = "We're inside";
    } else {
        $foo = "We're outside";
    }
    echo $foo;
}

class Choppa {
    public function getStatus() {
        getToDaChoppa($this);
    }
}


getToDaChoppa(); // Would return "We're outside" 
( new Choppa )->getStatus(); // Would return "We're inside"
```

See https://ideone.com/WWg1Hl for a working example.